# Containment question about sets

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let A, B and C be three sets. We want to show that $B \subset A \subset C \Leftrightarrow A\cup B = A \cap C$.

To do this question, I began by showing the first direction ($\Rightarrow$) which I think I can do. I don't see how I can prove the other direction ($\Leftarrow$). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Quite elementary... If $B \subseteq A$, then their union: $A \cup B$ will be $A$ itself.

Comment: If $A \subseteq C$, then their intersection: $A \cap C$ will be the "common part to both, i.e. $A$ itself.

Comment: The formal proof must be as usual... (i) $A \cup B \subseteq A \cap B$ and (ii) $A \cap B \subseteq A \cup B$.

Comment: Having proved (i) and (ii), we may conclude that $A \cup B = A \cap B$.

Comment: For the other "direction", again two steps: (i) prove that $B \subseteq A$ and (ii) that $A \subseteq C$.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I did for the first direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other side,
note that $A \cap C \subset A \subset A \cup B$
Since $A \cap C = A \cup B$
$\therefore$ $A \cap C = A = A \cup B$.
Hence, $B \subset A \subset C$.

Comment: Ahhhhhh.. I see it now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A \cup B = A \cap C$. We wish to show $B \subset A \subset C$. Let $b \in B$. Then $b \in A \cup B$, but since $A \cup B = A \cap C$, we have in particular that $b \in A \cap C$. Hence $b \in A$; this means $B \subset A$. A similar argument shows $A \subset C$. You start with $a \in A$. Can you go from there?

Comment: I am actually not so sure....I understand the logic up until "You start with a is an element of A."

Comment: If you want to show that $A \subset C$, you have to show that if $a \in A$, then $a \in C$ also. The logic is very similar to the above argument: if $a \in A$, then $a \in A \cup B$, so in particular $a \in A \cap C$. Hence $a \in C$ and so $A \subset C$. This is, of course, assuming the sets $A$ and $B$ are nonempty. The case when they're empty can be handled separately.